# Oledb Syntax error ("missing operator") in query expression

Tags: c#, sql, oledb, oledbexception

I'm using ole db as follows:

```
_adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
_adapter.Fill(Set);
```

command.commandtext is populated with:

```
"SELECT [Roster$].[ID],[Roster$].[Name],[Roster$].[Level],[Events$].[Name],[Scores$].[Score] 
FROM [Roster$] 
Inner Join [Scores$] on [Scores$].[CompetitorId] = [Roster$].[ID] 
Inner Join [Events$] on [Events$].[ID] = [Scores$].[EventId] 
where [Roster$].[ID] = 1"
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '[Scores$].[CompetitorId] = [Roster$].[ID] Inner Join [Events$] on [Events$].[ID] = [Scores$].[EventId]'.
```

Not sure where I'm going wrong.

**Edit:**
I'm trying to connect to an Excel Database BTW

Comment: What database are you connected to?

Comment: You need some extra parens.  OLEDB needs some help figuring out where the joins belong.  Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23626514/how-to-do-an-inner-join-in-ssis-excel-source-component