# Multiple inner join on same table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have three tables :
Table a

```
UID
SellID
BuyID
SAMonth
```

Table B

```
ID
ZipCode
```

Table C

```
Zip Code
Latitude 
Longitude
```

Now i have to find distance between two ID's

Firstly i was having UID and based on that UID i tried to get two Zip code Corresponding to each ID using following code.

```
Select t1.UID,t1.SellID,z1.ZipCode, t1.BuyID, z2.ZipCode , SAMonth 
from tableA t1
inner join tableB z1 on t1.SellID Like z1.ID 
inner join tableB z2 on t1.BuyID Like z2.ID 
where Criteria
```

what is wrong in this code, i am getting Syntax error in this when i am adding second inner join. Also how to use this Zip to get latitude and longitude for both ID's

It is working with Like Keyword because of the difference of Format. After adding brackets its working.  How Can it be extended to 3rd table

Comment: Build the query in the GUI designer, and you'll see that is will replace _Like_ and set two sets of parenthesis.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Inner Join wih multiple table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19367565/sql-inner-join-wih-multiple-table)

Answer (score 1):

You need to put one of the joins into parens e.g.

```
Select t1.UID,t1.SellID,z1.ZipCode, t1.BuyID, z2.ZipCode , SAMonth 
  from ( tableA t1
         inner join tableB z1 on t1.SellID Like z1.ID )
         inner join tableB z2 on t1.BuyID Like z2.ID 
 where Criteria
```

The order this forces you to write is simply for parsing purposes, the optimizer will use whichever order it determines to be best.

As others have pointed out, your data element names (`ID`) suggest you should replace `like` with `=` (equals).

Adding a third table involves adding a further level of parens nesting e.g.

```
from ( ( tableA t1
         inner join tableB z1 on t1.SellID Like z1.ID )
         inner join tableB z2 on t1.BuyID Like z2.ID )
         inner join tableC z3 on z1.ZipCode = z3.ZipCode
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace that `like` with `=` equality comparison

```
inner join tableB z1 on t1.SellID = z1.ID 
inner join tableB z2 on t1.BuyID = z2.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select t1.UID,t1.SellID,z1.ZipCode, t1.BuyID, z2.ZipCode , t1.SAMonth 
from tableA t1
inner join tableB z1 on t1.SellID = z1.ID 
inner join tableB z2 on t1.BuyID = z2.ID
```