# Missing Operator in Query Expression

Tags: ms-access-2013

I have this code

```
SELECT Sales.InvoiceNo, Sales.SaleDate, Clients.Name, Clients.Address AS
ClientAdrs, Stock.Itemname, Stock.Tax, Stock.Price, Transactions.Qty, 
Transactions.NetValue,Transactions.TaxAmount, Transactions.TotalAmount, 
Sales.GrossNet, Sales.GrossTax, Sales.GrossTotal, Sales.PrintingCharge,
Sales.LabourCharge, Sales.AdjustableAmount,Sales.GrandTotal, Sales.InWords,
ShopeDetails.Address, ShopeDetails.Email, ShopeDetails.Mobile1,
ShopeDetails.Mobile2, ShopeDetails.TIN, ShopeDetails.AcN,ShopeDetails.IFC

FROM Sales 
INNER JOIN Clients
ON Sales.Cid = Clients.Cid 
INNER JOIN Transactions 
ON Sales.InvoiceNo = Transactions.InvoiceNo
INNER JOIN Stock 
ON Transactions.Sid = Stock.Sid 
INNER JOIN ShopeDetails 
ON Sales.Id = ShopeDetails.Id
```

and i get this error

> Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 
>   Sales.Cid = Clients.Cid INNER JOIN Transactions ON Sales.InvoiceNo = Transactions.InvoiceNo INNER JOIN Stock ON Transactions.Sid = Stock.Sid INNER JOIN ShopeDetails ON Sales.Id = ShopeDetails.I

Please Help anyone !!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access-SQL: Inner Join with multiple tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19367565/access-sql-inner-join-with-multiple-tables)

Comment: yes that was it putting join query within brackets solved the problem thanks @Andre

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Sales.InvoiceNo, Sales.SaleDate, Clients.Name, Clients.Address AS 
ClientAdrs,Stock.Itemname, Stock.Tax, Stock.Price, Transactions.Qty, 
Transactions.NetValue,Transactions.TaxAmount, Transactions.TotalAmount,
Sales.GrossNet, Sales.GrossTax, Sales.GrossTotal, Sales.PrintingCharge, 
Sales.LabourCharge, Sales.AdjustableAmount,Sales.GrandTotal, Sales.InWords,
ShopeDetails.Address, ShopeDetails.Email, ShopeDetails.Mobile1,
ShopeDetails.Mobile2, ShopeDetails.TIN, ShopeDetails.AcN,ShopeDetails.IFC 

FROM (((Sales INNER JOIN Clients ON Sales.Cid = Clients.Cid) 
       INNER JOIN Transactions ON Sales.InvoiceNo = Transactions.InvoiceNo) 
       INNER JOIN Stock ON Transactions.Sid = Stock.Sid )
       INNER JOIN ShopeDetails ON Sales.Id = ShopeDetails.Id
```

this solved the problem