# Access Multiple Left Joins - SQL Code

Tags: sql, ms-access, left-join

I am trying to join three tables together in microsoft access, allowing for null entries with `Table 1` being my primary table so all the records show.

I have this code that works linking only 2 tables.

```
SELECT [1].IDCode, [2].GiftDate, [2].FundId__1, [2].fund_name 
FROM 1 LEFT JOIN 2 ON [1].IDCode = [2].IDCode 
WHERE ((([1].IDCode) Is Not Null));
```

But I want to add a third.  I have this, but each time I try to run it, I get an error (Invalid Operation).

```
SELECT [1].IDCode, [2].GiftDate, [2].FundId__1, [2].fund_name, [3].Rep_Type
FROM (1 LEFT JOIN 2 ON [1].IDCode = [2].IDCode) LEFT JOIN 3 ON [1].IDCode = [3].IDCode
WHERE ((([1].IDCode) Is Not Null));
```

My code is now this and I'm still receiving the invalid operation.

```
SELECT [A].IDCode, [A].GiftDate, [A].FundId__1, [A].fund_name, [3].Rep_Type
FROM 
(SELECT [1].IDCode, [2].GiftDate, [2].FundId__1, [2].fund_name
FROM 1
LEFT JOIN 2
ON [1].IDCode = [2].IDCode) A
LEFT JOIN 3
ON [A].IDCode = [3].IDCode
WHERE ((([1].IDCode) Is Not Null));
```

Comment: The answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19367565/access-sql-inner-join-with-multiple-tables may help you

Comment: Will 3's always exist in 2s?  if so join though 2.  If not () order will matter and make this more of a challenge.

Comment: 3 will not always exist in 2.

Comment: I cannot recreate issue. Your second query runs fine in Access 2013. Maybe post your table schema as my example might not align with yours.

Answer (score 0):

If 1-->2-->3 then the third on join should be 2.idcode = 3.idcode

```
SELECT [1].IDCode, [2].GiftDate, [2].FundId__1, [2].fund_name, [3].Rep_Type
FROM (1 LEFT JOIN 2 ON [1].IDCode = [2].IDCode) LEFT JOIN 3 ON [2].IDCode = [3].IDCode
WHERE ((([1].IDCode) Is Not Null));
```

However if the joins is really back to 1...

Since Access is picky about the ()'s and joining back to 2.

So I don't get lost with the ()'s I just created an inline view to manage the joins.

```
SELECT [A].IDCode, [A].GiftDate, [A].FundId__1, [A].fund_name, [3].Rep_Type
FROM
(SELECT [1].IDCode, [2].GiftDate, [2].FundId__1, [2].fund_name
 FROM 1 
 LEFT JOIN 2 
   ON [1].IDCode = [2].IDCode) A
LEFT JOIN 3 
  ON [A].IDCode = [3].IDCode
WHERE [A].IDCode Is Not Null;
```

Comment: 1-> 2 and 1-> 3

I tried the bottom code subbing the A instead of 1/2, and I am still getting an Invalid Operation.

Comment: Should there be two or 1 underscore for FundID_1?  you seem to have 2 which is odd.  Alternative would be to create the A as a view and select from the view  perhaps access for some reason doesn't like the inline view.