# Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression VBA while multiple inner join

Tags: sql, vba, excel, adodb

I am getting below **Syntax error (missing operator)**

[image]

Please find my below VBA code.

```
Sub macro()

sql_string = "SELECT [Sheet2$].[Sr], [no], [Code], [Sheet3$].[Srr], [Family], [nos], [Sheet1$].[Sr], [LongName]" & _
" FROM [Sheet3$], [Sheet2$], [Sheet1$] INNER JOIN [Sheet2$] ON [Sheet2$].[Sr]=[Sheet3$].[Srr]" & _
" INNER JOIN [Sheet2$] ON [Sheet2$].[no]=[Sheet3$].[nos]"

sq = SQL_query(sql_string)

end sub

Function SQL_query(ByRef sql_string As Variant)

Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

strFile = ThisWorkbook.FullName
strCon = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & strFile _
& ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

cn.Open strCon

strSQL = sql_string

rs.Open strSQL, cn

Sheet5.Range("A21").CopyFromRecordset rs
End Function
```

Please find the below tables.

Table1-

[image]

Table2-

[image]

Table3-

[image]

Please guide where i am missing in the code.

Comment: which line does the code break on?  Is it `rs.Open strSQL, cn` ?

Comment: @ashleedawg Yes Sir..

Comment: In Access, ACE, I believe you can only join two tables at a time.  I've tried before and ended up frustrated (SQL Server, this would work).  You'd have to restructure it like this answer, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19367565/access-sql-inner-join-with-multiple-tables)

Comment: You can join multiple tables, I don't think that's the issue

Answer (score 2):

Thank all for the help, As per your guidance.

the below syntax are working for me for multiple inner join.

```
sql_string = "SELECT [Sheet2$].[Sr], [no], [Code], [Sheet3$]." & _
    "[nos], [Family], [Sheet1$].[LongName]" & _
    " FROM (([Sheet2$] INNER JOIN [Sheet3$] ON [Sheet2$].[Sr]=[Sheet3$].[Srr])" & _
    " INNER JOIN [Sheet1$] ON [Sheet1$].[Sr]=[Sheet3$].[Srr])"
```

Answer (score 1):

A good way to troubleshoot messy SQL queries in VBA is to break them up, since SQL will ignore all the extra spaces & line breaks but we will be able to better understand it, and find problems.

So, we could split your line with the query up like:

```
sql_string = "
    SELECT
        [Sheet2$].[Sr],
        [no],
        [Code], 
        [Sheet3$].[Srr], 
        [Family], 
        [nos], 
        [Sheet1$].[Sr], 
        [LongName]
    FROM [Sheet3$], [Sheet2$], [Sheet1$] 
    INNER JOIN [Sheet2$] 
        ON [Sheet2$].[Sr]=[Sheet3$].[Srr]
    INNER JOIN [Sheet2$] 
        ON [Sheet2$].[no]=[Sheet3$].[nos]"
```

and now we can see a few mix-ups in your joins, which I further tidied up below, as well as specified table names on all the field.  There's a couple issues, for example You can't join 3 tables to 1 table, but you can do a join between two tables, and then a join between "that" and the third table.

```
sql_string = "
    SELECT
        [Sheet2$].[Sr],
        [Sheet2$].[no],
        [Sheet2$].[Code], 

        [Sheet3$].[Srr], 
        [Sheet3$].[nos], 
        [Sheet3$].[Family], 


        [Sheet1$].[Sr], 
        [Sheet1$].[LongName]

    FROM [Sheet2$]
    INNER JOIN [Sheet3$]
        ON [Sheet2$].[Sr]=[Sheet3$].[Srr]

    INNER JOIN [Sheet1$] 
        ON [Sheet1$].[Sr]=[Sheet3$].[Srr]"
```

Paste that in to replace your `sql_string = "SELECT [Sheet2$]....` line (as is, ignore how long it is now)

Let me know how it goes!

---

### Here's a link to more info on [nested `Inner Joins` from Microsoft Support](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INNER-JOIN-Operation-b9e73ab6-884a-403e-9f22-cb502feae36a)

> You can also link several ON clauses in a JOIN statement, using the following syntax:
>
> ```
> SELECT fields
> FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2
> ON table1.field1compoprtable2.field1 AND
> ON table1.field2compoprtable2.field2) OR
> ON table1.field3compoprtable2.field3)];
> ```
>
> You can also **nest JOIN statements** using the following syntax:
>
> ```
> SELECT fields FROM table1 INNER JOIN (table2 INNER JOIN [( ]table3
> [INNER JOIN [( ]tablex [INNER JOIN ...)] ON
> table3.field3compoprtablex.fieldx)] ON
> table2.field2compoprtable3.field3) ON
>  table1.field1compoprtable2.field2;
> ```
>
> A `LEFT JOIN` or a `RIGHT JOIN` may be nested inside an `INNER JOIN`, but
>   an `INNER JOIN` may not be nested inside a `LEFT JOIN` or a `RIGHT JOIN`.
>   (That last part shouldn't apply in this case since you've got straight nested `INNER JOIN`s now.)