# How can i make INNER JOIN ON Table with two different tables SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

i have three tables `ITEM_UNT` , `ITEM`, `UNIT` How can i make `INNER JOIN` for `ITEM_UNT` WITH `ITEM` AND `UNIT` I used this statement and doesn't work :

```
SELECT
  ITEM_UNT.ITEM_NO, ITEM_UNT.ITEM_ID,ITEM_UNT.UNIT_NO,UNIT.UNIT_NO,
  UNIT.UNIT_NAME,ITEM.ITEM_ID, ITEM.ITEM_NAME
FROM ITEM_UNT,UNIT
INNER JOIN UNIT ON UNIT.UNIT_NO =  ITEM_UNT.UNIT_NO 
INNER JOIN ITEM ON ITEM.ITEM_ID =  ITEM_UNT.ITEM_ID
```

Comment: `FROM ITEM_UNT,UNIT` should be just `FROM ITEM_UNT`

Comment: stil the same error @GMB

Comment: Which error are you actually getting? Please edit your question to add that information.

Comment: Don't merge old join syntax (`,`) with modern one (`JOIN`).

Comment: The operator is missing @GMB

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: i'm using MS ACCESS @GMB

Comment: What does "not work" mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea what "not work" means, but you can at least write the query according to MS Access query syntax.  That would look like:

```
SELECT ITEM_UNT.ITEM_NO, ITEM_UNT.ITEM_ID, ITEM_UNT.UNIT_NO, UNIT.UNIT_NO,
       UNIT.UNIT_NAME, ITEM.ITEM_ID, ITEM.ITEM_NAME
FROM (ITEM_UNT INNER JOIN
      UNIT
      ON UNIT.UNIT_NO =  ITEM_UNT.UNIT_NO 
     ) INNER JOIN
     ITEM
     ON ITEM.ITEM_ID =  ITEM_UNT.ITEM_ID;
```

I also removed the repeated `ITEM` reference.

Answer (score 0):

You have the Unit table twice with no alias... try

```
SELECT ITEM_UNT.ITEM_NO, ITEM_UNT.ITEM_ID,ITEM_UNT.UNIT_NO,UNIT.UNIT_NO, UNIT.UNIT_NAME,ITEM.ITEM_ID, ITEM.ITEM_NAME
FROM ITEM_UNT
INNER JOIN UNIT ON UNIT.UNIT_NO =  ITEM_UNT.UNIT_NO 
INNER JOIN ITEM ON ITEM.ITEM_ID =  ITEM_UNT.ITEM_ID
```

Comment: you doesn't change in my statement

Comment: Yes, in your question you have UNIT next to ITEM_UNT , I took that out.  Also, do you have an ITEM_NO on your table ITEM_UNT table as well as ITEM_ID?

Comment: yes i have ITEM_NO in ITEM_UNT as a PK and I have also ITEM_ID in ITEM_UNT as FK which is a PK in ITEM Table

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below :

### Option 1:

```
select iu.item_no,
       iu.item_id,
       iu.unit_no,
       u.unit_no,
       u.unit_name,
       i.item_id,
       i.item_name
from   item_unt iu
inner  join unit u
on     u.unit_no = iu.unit_no
inner  join item i
on     i.item_id = iu.item_id;
```

### Option 2:

```
select iu.item_no,
       iu.item_id,
       iu.unit_no,
       u.unit_no,
       u.unit_name,
       i.item_id,
       i.item_name
from   item_unt iu,
       unit     u,
       item     i
where  u.unit_no = iu.unit_no
and    i.item_id = iu.item_id;
```

Share some details of each table as well for better understanding the issue.

Comment: the option 1 doesn't work but the option 2 it works fine

Comment: Option 2 is old style join and should be avoided, just check your syntax and tells us what error message you got. Promote the use of  explict `JOIN` sintaxis, Aaron Bertrand wrote a nice article [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) about it.

Comment: In access you need to use parenthesis for each join. check here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/access/concepts/structured-query-language/perform-joins-using-access-sql

Comment: the error is : The operator is missing inner  join unit u
on     u.unit_no = iu.unit_no
inner  join item i
on     i.item_id = iu.item_id; @JuanCarlosOropeza

Comment: As @Juan said I think you need to use `FROM (item_unt iu INNER JOIN unit u ON u.unit_no = iu.unit_no) INNER JOIN item i ON i.item_id = iu.item_id` for the JOIN version.

Comment: thanks @DarrenBartrup-Cook but if i want to join another table how can i add it ?

Comment: @Borkan below will be the syntax for multiple tables:
select iu.item_no,
       iu.item_id,
       iu.unit_no,
       u.unit_no,
       u.unit_name,
       i.item_id,
       i.item_name
from   ((item_unt iu
inner  join unit u
on     u.unit_no = iu.unit_no)
inner  join item i
on     i.item_id = iu.item_id)
inner join tablex;
More details at : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19367565/access-sql-inner-join-with-multiple-tables

Comment: Just add the table as another join and put the brackets in - `FROM ((item_unt iu INNER JOIN unit u ON u.unit_no = iu.unit_no) INNER JOIN item i ON i.item_id = iu.item_id) INNER JOIN anothertable at ON anothertable.foreign_key = iu.item_id`.  Note - 2 brackets after FROM which close before each new join.

Answer (score 0):

You should not mix the comma separated  list of tables  and the explicit JOIN  clause

```
SELECT  ITEM_UNT.ITEM_NO
      , ITEM_UNT.ITEM_ID
      , ITEM_UNT.UNIT_NO
      , UNIT.UNIT_NO
      , UNIT.UNIT_NAME
      , ITEM.ITEM_ID
      , ITEM.ITEM_NAME
FROM ITEM_UNT
INNER JOIN UNIT ON UNIT.UNIT_NO =  ITEM_UNT.UNIT_NO 
INNER JOIN ITEM ON ITEM.ITEM_ID =  ITEM_UNT.ITEM_ID
```