# MS Access join with 3 tables, but showing all values of the main table

Tags: sql, ms-access, join

This are my tables:

[image]

Each zaehler can have 0 or 1 module and each module can have 0 or 1 simkarten
zaehler is my "main table"

i want a query that shows all zaehler and if there is a module, show all fields of module and if the module has a simkarten also show all entrys of that table.

I tried this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (zaehler
left JOIN module ON zaehler.modulnummer = module.modulnummer )
```

and the result was this:

[image]

Looks good, but i also want to see all columns of simkarten, so i tried this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (simkarten
INNER JOIN module ON simkarten.simnr = module.simnr )
INNER JOIN zaehler ON module.modulnummer = zaehler.modulnummer
```

The result is this:

[image]

I get only one entry back. It is the entry that has both, a module and a simkarten entry.

What i want is to see all zaehler entries, like in my first query, but also all fields of simkarten like in my 2nd query.

How can I archive this?

UPDATE:

Its working now, this is the query i used:

```
SELECT *
FROM (zaehler
LEFT JOIN module ON zaehler.modulnummer = module.modulnummer)
LEFT JOIN simkarten ON module.simnr = simkarten.simnr
```

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320052/266284)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (untested):

```
SELECT a.zaehlernummer,a.herrsteller,a.modulnummer,c.simmnr,c.ip
FROM simkarten a
INNER JOIN module b ON a.modulnummer = b.modulnummer
INNER JOIN simkarten1 c ON b.simnr =  c.simnr
```

Look here for additional details:

- https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-multiple-joins-for-beginners-with-examples/
- [Access-SQL: Inner Join with multiple tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19367565/access-sql-inner-join-with-multiple-tables)

Comment: hmm a (simkarten) doesnt have the column modulnummer, so it does not work

Comment: As you discovered: 1) "inner join" assumes that every simkarten has a corresponding module, and every module has a corresponding simkarten1 record. 2) "inner join" should generally be your *first choice". 3) Use "left outer join" if the left table (e.g. "module" in "simkarten join on module") might NOT have any corresponding matches) 4) The alternate syntax I gave you is applicable to any kind of join.

Comment: Still cant get it to work. It says "JOIN expression not supported"

Comment: Q: What exactly is the syntax that's giving the "not supported" error?  Look here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/left-join-right-join-operations-ebb18b36-7976-4c6e-9ea1-c701e9f7f5fb.  Are you using this ("left join") syntax?