# Joining multiple access database tables - Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression

Tags: c#, sql, database, ms-access, oledb

I am trying to join multiple tables from an access database. When I join two it works fine, but I need to join 9. Trying to join 3 like so gives the error:

```
Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression
```

Here is my command:

```
OleDbCommand gpInfoCommand = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM GPInformation " +
                                              "LEFT JOIN GPAvailability ON GPInformation.ID=GPAvailability.GPID " +
                                              "LEFT JOIN GPCustomPayRates ON GPInformation.ID=GPCustomPayRates.GPID", connection);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MS Access requires parentheses around joins when there is more than one. See the examples here: [Is it possible to do a 3 table join in MS-Access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2743231/is-it-possible-to-do-a-3-table-join-in-ms-access)

Answer (score 1):

MS Access has an arcane syntax for multiple joins that requires parentheses:

```
SELECT *
FROM (GPInformation LEFT JOIN
      GPAvailability
      ON GPInformation.ID = GPAvailability.GPID
     ) LEFT JOIN
     GPCustomPayRates
     ON GPInformation.ID = GPCustomPayRates.GPID;
```