# Access-SQL: Inner Join a table with multiple copies of another table

Tags: sql, ms-access, vb6, ado

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19367565/access-sql-inner-join-with-multiple-tables) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2743231/is-it-possible-to-do-a-3-table-join-in-ms-access) made a great overview on joining three tables. But suppose we have a table *Freights* with fields *From* and *To* linked to *Destinations* table. In a Data Scheme I see *Destinations_1* table, but when I try to use it in a query, it is not present. What to do?

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and expected results?

Comment: Shows your query, please...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Destinations_1 is the way Access internally aliases it.  What you need to do is open the SQL window and manually alias it to something a little more distinct.  There's no bigger pet peeve or worse coding offense than to let Access name everything for you.  For instance, Field28 doesn't mean bubkus to the next guy coming in to take over your database, but txtStartDate will make it pretty simple to figure out what it holds.  Similarly, Destinations_1 leaves the incoming coder pretty confused.  Go into your SQL and fix this, so it looks more like:

```
SELECT * FROM Destination as PrimDestination
INNER JOIN Destination as SecDestination
ON PrimDestination.MyField = SecDestination.MyField
```

It will make much more sense to you once you see this layout, it will make more sense in the Design View, and it will make more sense to any future admin of the DB.